# Google Analytics Funnel With Steps for Google, Facebook or Twitter Login

Tags: google-analytics

I have a goal in my site for users to download some content, but they need to be logged in. So, if they are not the system prompts them to either login or register.

For both these actions they can use services like Google accounts, Facebook ID, Twitter ID, etc.

How can I create a funnel in Google Analytics, where the people that leave to login with Google, and come back to finish the goal, don't drop off?

Comment: Why should they drop off? It would be within the same session so if you create the pages before and after the login it should track them correctly I would think.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible for Google Analytics to have visibility into what happens when users leave your site.   Google Analytics can only measure pages on which you have installed the tracking snippet.  When you send a user over to Facebook to sign in, you have no way of figuring out where in the Facebook login process they dropped out.

It sounds like you may be experiencing an issue where none of the users appear to come back to your site from logging in.  This may be because Universal Analytics starts a new session any time a user comes back with an external referrer.   You don't want users that come back to your site from logging in have a new session.   For a solution to that problem see: [When using Google and Facebook for social login, how to prevent misattributed session referrers and goal conversions in Google Analytics?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52812/when-using-google-and-facebook-for-social-login-how-to-prevent-misattributed-se)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook, and Twiitter provide callbacks for when a user logs in to your site using their networks. You can use this callback or a return URL to fire off a virtual page view, or event in Analytics to gather some basic login info in to a funnel see this answer at SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/10883243/804087