# Track visitors who come back to an application from email verification links

Tags: google-analytics

I have an app, which uses an **email verification** process on signup. After user's input is validated, the app sends out a link to user's **email asking to confirm their address**.

Is there a way to create a `Goal Funnel` which will have the confirmation link as the Goal URL (last step). In my case: confirmation links are generated dynamically:

```
.../verifying_email/8df11345-...-46b9-...-ffbc55fc9917
```

I am looking into [Google Analytic's user identification option (User ID)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id), but not sure if this will work with Goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to specify your goal URLs.  From https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1116091?hl=en#matchTypes

> #### Regular Expression Match—for matching on multiple criteria:
>
> A regular expression uses special characters to enable wildcard and flexible matching. This is useful when the stem, trailing parameters, or both, can vary in the URLs for the same webpage.
>
> For example, if a user could be coming from one of many subdomains, and your URLs use session identifiers, you could use a regular expression to define the constant element of your URL. For example, `checkout.cgi\?page=1` will match `http://sports.example.com/checkout.cgi?page=1&id=002` as well as `http://fishing.example.com/checkout.cgi?page=1&language=fr&id=119`.
>
> As another example, you could use regular expressions to set a goal for a user goes to any page in a subdirectory: `^/sports/.*`.

So you could use the regular expression:

```
.*/verifying_email/.*
```

Comment: Thought of this too. Would it work when the visitor abandons the page and then comes back via the signup link? Will this still be considered the same session?

Comment: In many cases, yes.   Google Analytics starts a new session when there is an external referrer.   In cases where the user clicked from web mail, they might get a new session.   You could counteract this by putting common webmail into the referrer exclusion list, or use [a meta refresh to strip the referrer](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52812/when-using-google-and-facebook-for-social-login-how-to-prevent-misattributed-se/64978#64978).   The user would also have to follow the link within the session timeout period (by default 30 minutes, although there is a setting for it.)